# If $f:X \to [0,1]$ is an onto continuous closed map and $\{f^{-1} (y)\}$ is compact for every $y \in [0,1]$, then is X necessarily compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $f:X \to [0,1]$ is an onto continuous closed map
and $\{f^{-1} (y)\}$ is compact for every $y \in [0,1]$, then 
is X necessarily compact?

Now continuous image of a compact set is compact. Again $X$ is the uncountable union of compact sets now we also have that $X^*=\{f^{-1} (\{z\}) | z \in [0,1]\}$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ hence compact now is $X$ is compact?

In [If $f:X \to [0,1]$ be an onto continuous map and $\{f^{-1} (y)\}$ is compact then Is $X$ compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289801/if-fx-to-0-1-be-an-onto-continuous-map-and-f-1-y-is-compact-the) closedness is not there.

Comment: You might want to highlight the difference between this question and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1289801/27978? Or at least reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true. Check at the end of [the Wikipedia page on proper maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) for a proof:

[image]

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged on Stack Exchange (whatever you're linking to could get edited, deleted, moved, etc., and then what's the point of your answer?) Copy the content into your post here to ensure it is saved.